# What cameras are lenses for a Canon EOS 300 compatible with?

Tags: canon, dslr, lens-mount, compatibility

I'm researching various DSLRs. I've got a couple of lenses that worked with a Canon EOS 300. What cameras would these lenses be compatible with? How can I determine if they are compatible with a particular camera?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We have lots of info on lens compatibility and moving lenses from film to digital already on this site. I'd highly recommend trying our search function for more info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canon EOS 300 film camera from the early 2000s uses the [EF lens mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_lens_mount).  This same mount has been used by Canon for almost 30 years now.

Since the EF mount is still being actively used by Canon today for all of their DSLRs, you really don't have to worry about a thing. All Canon DSLRs can accept all EF-mount lenses. You can use your old lenses with no problem.

Now *whether* you should use your old lenses on a newer camera is a whole other question. If they were basic entry-level kit lenses 15 years ago, they might not be worth even digging out of storage. But if you did invest in them then it's worth looking further into.

Some additional topics worth reading:

- [How do SLR lenses connect to the body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/73549/how-do-slr-lenses-connect-to-the-body)
- [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)
- [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)
- [Are Canon EOS and Nikon DSLR lenses interchangeable?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2904/are-canon-eos-and-nikon-dslr-lenses-interchangeable)

Comment: Thos is true for canon lenses, but some third party lenses (notably older sigma) have problems with auto focus.

Comment: @ths Not just AF. I have an older Sigma 70-300 I used on a film Rebel back in the 90s. It will only work on my digital EOS bodies if the aperture is manually set to the widest setting. If the aperture is set at any other setting and I press the shutter button it locks the camera up that requires a power cycle/battery removal to reset.

Comment: @dpollitt The EOS 300 obviously can't use EF-S lenses, but saying  "All Canon DSLRs can accept all EF-mount lenses" might not be properly understood by everyone to not include EF-S lenses.

Comment: @MichaelClark That would be why I linked to the entire Q&A on EF-S. I wasn't trying to reinvent the wheel here and cover a thesis in EF technology. Pretty sure the OP with 20 year old EF lenses got what he needed from my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP is not the only person who might read that. People don't always read the links, either. I'd just hate to think someone with a bag full of EF-S lenses buys a FF body from someone they can't sell it back and then discovers all of their lenses are useless on it.